# using AJAX to update query

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written a code by watching some tutorial. What it does is, if one writes a message, it adds it to database without reloading. The problem is it doesnt show me the updated database. It shows the database that was at the time of loading. What function should i add in function() to be able to that. I dont have much knowledge of javascript so if you can add it in the code it will me really helpful. Thanks

```
<html>
<?include_once('database.php')?>
           <head>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
              <script>
                 $(function () {

                   $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

                     e.preventDefault();

                     $.ajax({
                       type: 'get',
                       url: 'home.php',
                       data: $('form').serialize(),
                       success: function () {
                           $('#comment').val('');

                       }
                     });

                   });

                 });
              </script>
           </head>
           <!--body-->
           <body>
              <?php         
                 if(isset($_GET["new_message"]))
                 {
                     $new_message = $_GET["new_message"];
                     $sql="INSERT INTO Messages(id, message, time, me) VALUES ('$session_usernumber', '$new_message',now(),'1')";
                     if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                 {
                     echo"can not";
                 }

                 }

                 ?>
           </body>
           <?php
$message_query="SELECT * FROM Messages Where id='$session_usernumber'";
$result = $con->query($message_query);
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row= $result->fetch_assoc())
                  {

                 echo $row['message'];
                             }

              }
              else
              {
                  echo"Oops! You don't have any message";
              }

              ?>
           <div class="footer">
           <form  class="search_footer" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate >
              <input id='comment' autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="new_message"  placeholder="Type your message here.." required="required" class="textbox">
              <input value="Send message" name="submit" type="submit" class="button">
           </form>
        </html>
```

Comment: Quite a bit to cover there. You will need to return useful data from your `home.php` script (preferably in JSON format), and then utilize that returned data in your ajax success function. Too many details to cover, I'm not sure many will offer to write up all that guessing on your database and other content in `home.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet, i think the problem is because your form doesn't send the message data to the database.

```
<div class="footer">
           <form  class="search_footer" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate >
              <input id='comment' autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="new_message"  placeholder="Type your message here.." required="required" class="textbox">
              <input value="Send message" name="submit" type="submit" class="button">
           </form>
        </html>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 url:'getmessages.php',type:'GET',success: function(message){console.log(message);}
 });

 $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
 var data = $('#comment').val();
                     $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: 'home.php',
                       data: {new_message: data},
                       success: function(response) {
                           console.log(response);

                       }
                     });

                   });

                 });
              </script>
```

home.php file:

```
<?php         


if(isset($_POST["new_message"]))
             {
                 $new_message = $_POST["new_message"];
                 $sql="INSERT INTO Messages(id, message, time, me) VALUES ('$session_usernumber', '$new_message',now(),'1')";
                 if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
             {
                 echo"can not";
             }
```

getmessages.php

```
<?php
$message_query="SELECT * FROM Messages Where id='$session_usernumber'";
$result = $con->query($message_query);
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row= $result->fetch_assoc())
                  {

                 echo $row['message'];
                             }

              }
              else
              {
                  echo"Oops! You don't have any message";
              }

              ?>
```

Comment: it worked, but it is reloading the page which i dont want. I want it to be periodic and without reloading so that i can get other people message without having to send them a message and then reload the page

Comment: @AhsanAhmed I've edited the reply, try now. Remember to separate the php code from your html and to create two separate php script files that will be called by ajax.